# Electron worker: Hidden BrowserWindow causes front to lag

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a hidden browserwindow as my worker.
There are many requests sent at the same time, that is being sent in the worker.
Even though the requests are being sent from the worker, it causes the main browserwindow to kind of freeze and lag.

Any solutions..?

Comment: could you share some code snippet so that we can identify the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a gotcha in the world of Electron. When you create a browser window and tab away from it, Chromium starts throttling all the JavaScript that is executed in that background window, the assumption is the user does not care about the processes inside that window. So Chromium artificially limits the number of resources available to that browser window.

You can pass in an additional configuration option to ensure that Chromium does not do that throttling on your browser window.

If you share your `BrowserWindow` class, I could provide a solution, but you have not shared any code thus far.

Based on what you provided below, this is what the solution would look like:

```
let workerWin = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: { backgroundThrottling: false }
});
```

Typically, I would be pulling off `app` and `BrowserWindow` from `electron` like so:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;
```

Create a `mainWindow` variable like so:

```
let mainWindow;
```

and then applying that `app` object with an on ready method like so:

```
const electron = require("electron");

const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

let mainWindow;

app.on("ready", () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: { backgroundThrottling: false }
  });

});
```

Comment: ``let workerWin = new BrowserWindow({show: false});``

Comment: @Hobey823, so after my implementation, when you toggle to another application on your desktop, there is still lag with your Electron application? Also, you should probably share more code or include in your OP the information about the non-local file.

Comment: I've said that it does a lot of requests.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're discovering that putting a lot of app-related information into the regular IPC between the main process and render process(es) ends up with impacting app performance. James Long has written about this - https://jlongster.com/secret-of-good-electron-apps

Instead of using a hidden render window (BrowserWindow) to run your non-render code, think about forking the main process and running IPC to/from there.

Comment: The code that is running in the hidden browserwindow is not a local file, as far as i've seen you cannot run a non-local file by forking with child_process..?